# Update stylesheet without losing original style

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets

I am creating qpushbuttons with a certain style and then updating the style sheet to color them later on. However when I do this it overwrites the original style. Is there a way I can update or append to the object's stylesheet without losing it or having to redefine everything again?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout,QPushButton, QMenu, QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QCoreApplication, Qt, QLine, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QFont,QPainter, QPainterPath, QPixmap


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))   

        color = QPushButton('color', self)
        color.clicked.connect(self.color)
        color.resize(100,115)
        color.move(0, 100)

        buttons= ['button1','button2','button3']
        self.pybutton = {}
        x=0
        t = 0
        for i in buttons:
            t = t + 100
            x+=1
            self.pybutton[str(x)] = QPushButton(i, self) 
            self.pybutton[str(x)].setObjectName('btn' + str(x))
            self.pybutton[str(x)].resize(100,100)
            self.pybutton[str(x)].move(400-int(t),100)
            self.pybutton[str(x)].setStyleSheet('QPushButton {max-width: 75px;text-align:center;padding-left: 20px; max-height: 60px; font-size: 20px;}')
        self.statusBar()
    def status(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print('PyQt5 button click')
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')

    def color(self):
        for i in self.pybutton:
            self.pybutton[str(i)].objectName()
            if self.pybutton[str(i)].objectName() == 'btn1':
                self.pybutton[str(i)].setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
            else:
                self.pybutton[str(i)].setStyleSheet("background-color: red")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Answer (score 4):

A possible solution would be to have the stylesheet set with the `styleSheet()` method and then analyze the text and modify it as necessary but that can be very hard. Another better solution is to use the [QSS Property Selector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) and choose the color by modifying a property:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))   

        color = QPushButton('color', self)
        color.clicked.connect(self.color)
        color.resize(100,115)
        color.move(0, 100)

        buttons= ['button1','button2','button3']
        self.pybutton = {}

        qss = """
        QPushButton{
            max-width: 75px;
            text-align:center;
            padding-left: 20px; 
            max-height: 60px; 
            font-size: 20px;
        }
        QPushButton[color = "0"]{
            background-color: green;
        }
        QPushButton[color = "1"]{
            background-color: red;
        }
        """

        for i, text in enumerate(buttons):
            btn = QPushButton(text, self) 
            btn.setObjectName('btn{}'.format(i))
            btn.setGeometry(300-i*100, 100, 100,100)
            btn.setStyleSheet(qss)
            self.pybutton[str(i)] = btn

    def color(self):
        for i, btn in self.pybutton.items():
            if btn.objectName() == 'btn1':
                btn.setProperty("color", "0")
            else:
                btn.setProperty("color", "1") 
            btn.style().polish(btn)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: What if you have no clue about all other parameters because they use the default palette?

Answer (score 0):

This is a "hack" way to update style sheet, let's go straight to my code example.

```
class ButtonStyle:
    def __init__(self: QPushButton):
        self.setMinimumSize(self.sizeHint())

    @property
    def style_sheet(self) -> str:
        return self.styleSheet() + '\n'

    def set_bg_color(self, color: str):
        # name or hex str
        style = self.style_sheet \
                + """
                QPushButton#%s {
                    background-color: %s;
                }
                """ % (self.objectName(), color)

        self.setStyleSheet(style)

    def set_hover_bg_color(self, color: str):
        style = self.style_sheet \
                + """
                QPushButton#%s:hover{
                    background-color: %s;
                } 
                """ % (self.objectName(), color)

        self.setStyleSheet(style)

    def set_pressed_bg_color(self, color: str):
        style = self.style_sheet \
                + """
                QPushButton#%s:pressed {
                    background-color: %s;
                }
                """ % (self.objectName(), color)
        self.setStyleSheet(style)

    def set_border_radius(self, px: int):
        """set px radius
        """
        style = self.style_sheet \
                + """
                QPushButton#%s {
                    border-radius: %spx;
                }""" % (self.objectName(), px)
        self.setStyleSheet(style)


class Button(QPushButton, ButtonStyle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Button, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.set_default_object_name()

    def set_default_object_name(self):
        """set default object name to :Class: Name
        """
        self.setObjectName(self.__class__.__name__)


class RedButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RedButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.init_style()

    def init_style(self):
        self.set_bg_color('#f44336')
        self.set_hover_bg_color('#e57373')
        self.set_pressed_bg_color('#ffcdd2')
        self.set_border_radius(8)
        print(self.styleSheet())


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Button Split Style')
        v_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = Button('NORMAL')
        self.red_button = RedButton('RED')
        v_layout.addStretch(1)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.button)
        v_layout.addWidget(self.red_button)
        v_layout.addStretch(1)

        self.widget.setLayout(v_layout)
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The `\n` is to fromat style str.
It works like "update" operation, the new style will override the same style defined before it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the QSS string to a dict (`MyQSS.str_to_mapping` in the following code) and modify the dict
2. Convert the modified dict back to a string (`MyQSS.mapping_to_str` in the following code)
3. Call `setSytleSheet` with the new string (`MyQSS.set_value` in the following code)

```py
import re
import sys
from typing import Dict, Union

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
)

QSSMapping = Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, str]]]


class MyQSS:
    @classmethod
    def mapping_to_str(cls, mapping: QSSMapping) -> str:
        qss_str = ""
        for selector, declaration in mapping.items():
            if isinstance(declaration, str):
                # str_to_mapping requires every value ends with ";"
                if not declaration.endswith(";"):
                    declaration = f"{declaration};"
                qss_str += f"{selector}: {declaration}\n"
            else:
                qss_str += f"{selector} {{\n"  # }}
                for property, value in declaration.items():
                    # str_to_mapping requires every value ends with ";"
                    if not value.endswith(";"):
                        value = f"{value};"
                    qss_str += f"{property}: {value}\n"
                qss_str += "}\n"
        return qss_str

    @classmethod
    def str_to_mapping(cls, qss_str: str) -> QSSMapping:
        """
        This func requires that in the qss_str
            (1) Every value ends with ";"
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt" ✗
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt;" ✓
            (2) The trailing ";" be attached to the value and separated
                from the subsequent token
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt ;" ✗
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt;" ✓
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt;max-width: 75px;" ✗
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt; max-width: 75px;" ✓
            (3) The trailing ":" of a property be attached to the lhs property and
                separated from the rhs value
                e.g., "font-size :11pt;" ✗
                e.g., "font-size : 11pt;" ✗
                e.g., "font-size: 11pt;" ✓
        This func allows that in the qss_str
            (1) Values have whitespaces
                e.g., "font-family: Noto Sans;" ✓
            (2) Selectors have whitespaces
                e.g., "QDialog QPushButton { color: black; }" ✓
                e.g., "QDialog > QPushButton { color: black; }" ✓
            (3) "{" and "}" are not separated from others
                e.g., "QDialog QPushButton{color: black;}" ✓
        Later value for the same property will override the previous one
        The returned dict will always has a trailing ";" across its values
        """
        selector_declaration_mapping = {}
        cur_selector = None
        cur_property = None
        qss_str = qss_str.replace("{", " { ").replace("}", " } ")
        token_gen = iter(qss_str.split())
        while (token := next(token_gen, None)) is not None:
            if token == "{":
                pass
            elif token == "}":
                cur_selector = None
            elif token.endswith(":"):
                cur_property = token.rstrip(":")
            elif cur_property is not None:
                if cur_selector is None:
                    value_prev = selector_declaration_mapping.get(cur_property, "")
                    value = f"{value_prev} {token}" if not value_prev.endswith(";") else token
                    selector_declaration_mapping[cur_property] = value.lstrip()
                else:
                    if cur_selector not in selector_declaration_mapping:
                        selector_declaration_mapping[cur_selector] = {}
                    value_prev = selector_declaration_mapping[cur_selector].get(cur_property, "")
                    value = f"{value_prev} {token}" if not value_prev.endswith(";") else token
                    selector_declaration_mapping[cur_selector][cur_property] = value.lstrip()
                if token.endswith(";"):
                    cur_property = None
            else:
                cur_selector = f"{cur_selector} {token}" if cur_selector is not None else token
        return selector_declaration_mapping

    @classmethod
    def set_value(cls, widget: QWidget, selector: str, property: str, value: str) -> None:
        qss_str = widget.styleSheet()
        selector_declaration_mapping: QSSMapping = cls.str_to_mapping(qss_str)
        property_value_mapping = selector_declaration_mapping.get(selector, {})
        if isinstance(property_value_mapping, str):
            raise ValueError(f"{selector} is not a valid selector")
        property_value_mapping[property] = value
        selector_declaration_mapping[selector] = property_value_mapping

        widget.setStyleSheet(cls.mapping_to_str(selector_declaration_mapping))


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(400, 400))

        color = QPushButton("color", self)
        color.clicked.connect(self.color)
        color.resize(100, 115)
        color.move(0, 100)

        buttons = ["button1", "button2", "button3"]
        self.pybutton = {}
        x = 0
        t = 0
        for i in buttons:
            t = t + 100
            x += 1
            self.pybutton[str(x)] = QPushButton(i, self)
            self.pybutton[str(x)].setObjectName("btn" + str(x))
            self.pybutton[str(x)].resize(100, 100)
            self.pybutton[str(x)].move(400 - int(t), 100)
            self.pybutton[str(x)].setStyleSheet(
              # "QPushButton {max-width: 75px;text-align:center;padding-left: 20px; max-height: 60px; font-size: 20px;}"
                "QPushButton {max-width: 75px; text-align: center; padding-left: 20px; max-height: 60px; font-size: 20px;}"
            )
        self.statusBar()

    def status(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print("PyQt5 button click")
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + " was pressed")

    def color(self):
        for i in self.pybutton:
            self.pybutton[str(i)].objectName()
            if self.pybutton[str(i)].objectName() == "btn1":
                # self.pybutton[str(i)].setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
                MyQSS.set_value(self.pybutton[str(i)], "*", "background-color", "green")
            else:
                # self.pybutton[str(i)].setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
                MyQSS.set_value(self.pybutton[str(i)], "*", "background-color", "red")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```